# Can we perform async operations within a test using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am learning testing with Jasmine and I'm looking for a bit of clarification on `async` testing to further my understanding.

In the following code, the test in the first spec works but the second version where I've removed the `beforeEach` and moved the async calls into the `it` does not.

```
describe("Working Asnc", function() {
 var value = 0;

 function funcRunInBackground() {
   value = 1;
};  

 function wrapFuncRunInBackground(done) {  
    setTimeout(function() {
       funcRunInBackground();
       done();
    }, 2000);       
 }    

 beforeEach(function(done) {
     wrapFuncRunInBackground(done);          
 });                 

 it("should be greater than 0", function() {
   expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
 });
```

});

describe("Not working Asnc", function() {
      var value = 0;

```
 function funcRunInBackground() {
   value = 1;
 };  

 function wrapFuncRunInBackground(done) {  
   setTimeout(function() {
       funcRunInBackground();
       done();
   }, 2000);       
 }                 

 it("should be greater than 0", function(done) {
   wrapFuncRunInBackground(done);       
   expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
 });
```

});

[code pen here](http://codepen.io/davyCassidy/pen/jqmpjB)

Can we do the asnc operation from with the test itself if this is ever required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```js
 it("should be greater than 0", function(done) {
   wrapFuncRunInBackground(done);       
   expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
 });
```

to

```js
 it("should be greater than 0", function(done) {
   wrapFuncRunInBackground(function() {       
     expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
     done();
   });
 });
```

Callbacks don't pause the execution, so in your original snippet there is nothing that prevents the `expect(...)` call from being run before the asynchronous callback of `wrapFuncRunInBackground` is called.

`done` is not magic, it's just a normal function that marks the test as completed upon invocation...

Comment: perfect, thanks.  I did have an attempt at this but must have left a piece out somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can not syncronize js async code that way. You just can not wait for async code would be executed without using zallbacks/promises/co+generators/etc.
In your case it should be something like:

```
it("should be greater than 0", function(done) {
   wrapFuncRunInBackground(function(){
       expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
       done();
   });       
 });
```